# AWS ECS images in two task definitions using gitlab pipelines

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab-ci, amazon-ecs, continuous-deployment, gitlab-ci.yml

I have come pretty far in case of setting up everything necessary for building, deploying and running an docker image to AWS ECS.

So far I have acheived:

- docker image is built and pushed to my private gitlab container registry
- AWS ECS cluster, services and task definitions are setup, up and running. I have two task definitions within one cluster service. Both containers are running - on initial startup, ECS pulled images from gitlab registry successfully (React webapp, images differ in some frontend configurations only, thats why I have two containers/task definitions).

Now the problem:
I am trying to follow [official gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/cloud_deployment/) for deploying image to ECS. Just to be clear, I am using Fargate, not EC2. I have problem especially with `gitlab-ci.yml`, because in documentation, they refer to template which should be used for deployment.

[Template](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/AWS/Deploy-ECS.gitlab-ci.yml) itself consists of another 2 templates:

1. [build template](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Jobs/Build.gitlab-ci.yml)
2. [deploy template](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Jobs/Deploy/ECS.gitlab-ci.yml)

Since I cannot rely on these templates as they are, not just because they didn't work when I configured everything as described in the documentation, but mainly because I have two task definitions which must be deployed witin one CD job.

I have managed to copy deployment scripts into my own `gitlab-ci.yml` file in my repo. This is current version, which has only one task definition:

```
stages:
  - test
  - review
  - deploy
  - production
  - cleanup


  # deployment to AWS ECS
variables:
  AUTO_DEVOPS_PLATFORM_TARGET: ECS
  CI_AWS_ECS_CLUSTER: app-development
  CI_AWS_ECS_SERVICE: app-frontend-dev-service
  CI_AWS_ECS_TASK_DEFINITION: app-frontend-dev-a
  #CI_AWS_ECS_TASK_DEFINITION_B: app-frontend-dev-b

.ecs_image:
  image: 'registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-ecs:latest'

.deploy_to_ecs:
  extends: .ecs_image
  dependencies: []
  script:
    - ecs update-task-definition

.review_ecs_base:
  stage: review
  extends: .deploy_to_ecs

.production_ecs_base:
  stage: production
  extends: .deploy_to_ecs
  environment:
    name: production

.stop_review_ecs_base:
  extends: .ecs_image
  stage: cleanup
  allow_failure: true
  script:
    - ecs stop-task

review_ecs:
  extends: .review_ecs_base
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    on_stop: stop_review_ecs
  rules:
    - if: '$AUTO_DEVOPS_PLATFORM_TARGET != "ECS"'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_KUBERNETES_ACTIVE || $KUBECONFIG'
      when: never
    - if: '$REVIEW_DISABLED'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'

stop_review_ecs:
  extends: .stop_review_ecs_base
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    action: stop
  rules:
    - if: '$AUTO_DEVOPS_PLATFORM_TARGET != "ECS"'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_KUBERNETES_ACTIVE || $KUBECONFIG'
      when: never
    - if: '$REVIEW_DISABLED'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'
      when: manual

review_fargate:
  extends: .review_ecs_base
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    on_stop: stop_review_fargate
  script:
    - ecs update-task-definition
  rules:
    - if: '$AUTO_DEVOPS_PLATFORM_TARGET != "FARGATE"'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_KUBERNETES_ACTIVE || $KUBECONFIG'
      when: never
    - if: '$REVIEW_DISABLED'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'

stop_review_fargate:
  extends: .stop_review_ecs_base
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    action: stop
  rules:
    - if: '$AUTO_DEVOPS_PLATFORM_TARGET != "FARGATE"'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_KUBERNETES_ACTIVE || $KUBECONFIG'
      when: never
    - if: '$REVIEW_DISABLED'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'
      when: manual

production_ecs:
  extends: .production_ecs_base
  rules:
    - if: '$AUTO_DEVOPS_PLATFORM_TARGET != "ECS"'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_KUBERNETES_ACTIVE || $KUBECONFIG'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'

production_fargate:
  extends: .production_ecs_base
  rules:
    - if: '$AUTO_DEVOPS_PLATFORM_TARGET != "FARGATE"'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_KUBERNETES_ACTIVE || $KUBECONFIG'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'
```

To be honest, I have no clue what are all these blocks of scripts (review, production, ...) doing. I will be happy for any advice of making this as simple as possible with running two task definitions but also following some best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found a solution to this after talks with AWS Support, which brought some more light into this problem, but I have managed to come up with a bit different solution than they suggested.

Their solution was to register a new task definition and then update service, which is fine, but only if you really need a new task revision for every deployment job, which I did not. I am using the same image name and same image tag.

Version with registering new task definition looks like this:

```
- aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json $CI_AWS_ECS_TASK_DEFINITION_FILE --family $FAMILY
- aws ecs update-service --cluster $CI_AWS_ECS_CLUSTER --service $CI_AWS_ECS_SERVICE --task-definition $CI_AWS_ECS_TASK_DEFINITION --desired-count 1
```

This solution creates many revisions and requires some cleanup jobs after deployment, so you dont end up with hundreds of revisions.

Reading AWS documentation, there was an easier way of pulling a new image using `--force-new-deployment`.

```
deploy:
  image: 'registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-ecs:latest'
  stage:
    deploy
  environment:
    name: dev
  script:
    - aws ecs update-service --cluster $CI_AWS_ECS_CLUSTER --service $CI_AWS_ECS_SERVICE  --force-new-deployment
```